# Address of Instruction that Caused exception ARM

Tags: arm

which register stores the address of instruction which caused an exception(eg DataAbort)

is it always lr-4 (in 32) or there is a specific register
in powerpc there is but in arm I dont know

Comment: You mean PC? (register 15)

Comment: yes the PC of the instruction which caused the exceptio

Comment: So if the current PC is not what would cause the data abort then it should be PC-8 if the code is in ARM mode or PC-4 if the code is in thumb mode. I say current PC at first because afaik debuggers tell you corrected PC but if you are reading values manually then you need to extract 2 instruction size from the PC.

Comment: when you are in exception handler, then it is Lr right. and lr-8 in arm mode would give the instruction address. right?

Comment: Yes (or no I'm not sure actually - sorry). I would read Cortex-A Series Programmer's Guide 12.3.

Comment: In 32-bit ARM, the address of an instruction that caused an exception (relative to LR) ... depends on the exception. Like auselen and scott say, it would be better to read the programmer's guide (for an overview) or the ARM ARM (for the definition). 64-bit ARM as well as the M profile microcontrollers have completely different exception handling models, both a lot less complex.

Answer (score 0):

For Cortex-A and Cortex-R, at entry to the Data Abort handler the LR of ABT mode will contain the address of the offending instruction +8 (no matter whether the offending instruction was in ARM state or Thumb state).

See section B1.8.3 (especially Table B1-7) of the [ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html) for details.